# Hibernate one-to-one mapping file

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-key-relationship

I have `Address` and `Organization` tables. `Address` has FK named `organizationID`.

`Address` class has following property:

```
Organization organization;
```

`Organization` class has following property:

```
Address address property;
```

Mapping for `Address`:

```
<one-to-one name="organization" class="entity3.Organization"
            constrained="true">
</one-to-one>
```

How can I specify FK column `organizationID`? If I put

```
<column name="OrganizationID" not-null="true"/>
```

between one-to-one tags I get XML parse error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `property-ref` property, like this:-

```
<one-to-one name="organization" class="entity3.Organization" property-ref="OrganizationID" constrained="true"/>
```

Comment: thanks for answer! do i put same thing in organization mapping file?

Comment: if you want to make it bidirectional, you typically put `<many-to-one name="..." class="..." column="...." unique="true"/>` in organization mapping file.

Comment: and i dont put anything in address mapping? please bear with me

Comment: No, put `<one-to-one ../>` in address mapping file. That gives you an unidirectional mapping... meaning, address domain have access to organization domain. If you want bidirectional mapping, then you need to add `<many-to-one .../>` in organization mapping file so that you can access from both sides. Typically, unidirectional suffices, but it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: org.hibernate.MappingException: property-ref [OrganizationID] not found on entity [entity3.Organization]
 why? i have that!

Answer (score 2):

You use "property-ref" on the mapping to specify the property of the other class to join to the primary key.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone

Comment: thanks for answer! do i put same thing in organization mapping file?